# test for condition m AND condition n using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating muti-level menu using jquery. When I click on a button in a given level I change the buttons colour and I display the next lower menu level for the button clicked.

For example, clicking "Polices" may show "New policy", "Renew policy", "Endorse policy" etc.

The "Policies" button is at level 1 and the others are at level 2. If I click another level 1 button I turn off (remove) the button colour class for all buttons except the button being clicked. For this button I toggle the button colour class (in case it's being clicked off or clicked a second time).

1) The problem comes when I click a level two button in that ALL the level one buttons' colour class are removed. So now I want to put type="level01" and type="level02" for the buttons in the different levels. (I call them buttons but they are actually anchor tags.)

This is my code to remove all but the current buttons' colour class:

```
// remove the menuA-open class from all class menuA objects except the one being toggled
$(".menuA[name!=" + $(this).text() +"]").removeClass("menuA-open");
```

Note that the text on the button (the anchor tag's innerHTML) is also in the name="" parameter.

Now I want to say something like:

```
($(".menuA[name!=" + $(this).text() +"]") and $("menu[type]==$(this)[type])).removeClass("menuA-open");
```

but I'm failing find how to 'and' these two conditions correctly in jquery.

2) I use the text() function on $(this) in

```
$(".menuA[name!=" + $(this).text() +"]").removeClass("menuA-open");
```

because the anchor tag's innerHTML has a small graphic appended to the text. So this works fine for text lengths less than 19 characters but from there on the test fails??

Can anyone please help?

Chris

Comment: can you put an example of the markup

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell what the question is here. Could you post all of the (relevant) code to reproduce the bug at http://jsfiddle.net/ and share a link? Also, the statements you are attempting to join are not really conditionals (don't evaluate to true/false) -- furthermore `and` isn't a javascript operator, it would be `&&`

Comment: Sure. You can see it working at http://www.inandrias.com/testbiz/inandrias.biz/menusrc/mainmenu.htm
If you right-click you can view the source.
The relevant CSS is:
    a.menuA.menuA-open span {
     background-image:url("images/toggle_up_dark.png");
     color:#789;
    }
Chris

Comment: p.s. `type` isn't a valid attribute for an anchor link. Make that a class name as well (elements can have multiple class names). `class="menuA level02"` is perfectly fine and the `.removeClass()` method (and so on) will still work fine and remove only what's specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Further Update:** Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/Jb2jP/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menuA").click(function(evnt) {

        evnt.preventDefault();

        $(".menuA").not(this).removeClass("menuA-open");

        // hide all other fieldset objects except the one being toggled
        $('fieldset').not($(this).next('fieldset')).hide();

        // toggle the fieldset following this link open or closed
        $(this).next('fieldset').toggle();

        // toggle the currently selected menuA-open class on or off
        $(this).toggleClass("menuA-open");
    });

    $("fieldset").mouseup(function() {
        return false;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(evnt) {
        // if user clicked anywhere outside our menus
        if ($(evnt.target).parent("a.menuA").length == 0) {
            // remove the menuA-open class from all class menuA objects
            $(".menuA").removeClass("menuA-open");
            // hide all fieldset objects
            $("fieldset").hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

---

**Update:** To chain multiple attribute-(not)-equals selectors together, simply concatenate them ([see jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)).

```
$(".menuA[name='abc'][type='123']").removeClass("menuA-open");
```

Specifically in your case though, this still probably won't be necessary:

```
var type = $(this).attr('type');
$(".menuA").not(this).filter("[type='"type"']").removeClass("menuA-open");
```

---

You can use the jquery [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) filter method to remove the current element from the matched set once you've done the selection:

```
$(".menuA").not(this).removeClass("menuA-open");
```

That is the way to do it.

---

As an example of how you *would* get your attempt working (not recommending this at all though):

```
$(".menuA[name!='" + $(this).text() +"']").removeClass("menuA-open");
```

You need to wrap the results of `$(this).text()` in literal quotes within your string, since it contains a space. That should be the only syntactic problem, though again the `.not()` filter is the safest and most intuitive way to go about this.

Comment: Cool, that takes care of my 2nd question. I will try it now and revert. Did you have any ideas on my first question, that of not removing the colour class when on a different menu level?

Chris

Comment: Interestingly the Maintenance tab with submenu "Subfile maintenance" still doesn't work even using the not(this) code?

I will investigate further and revert...

Chris

Comment: Sorry nbrooks, I must have been fiddling while you were looking, it's working now. I will make your multiple class change as put forward by you above, thank you, and revert...

Comment: @user1530235 That doesn't seem to have been the problem. You are using a (much) older version of jQuery, and something seems to be incompatible. Is there a reason you are doing this (legacy code)? Otherwise use the current release, and use the google hosted version to get bug fixes immediately. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11337651/803925

Comment: @user1530235 I have updated my answer and included a link to a full working example. Your `a` link is not included directly in your fieldset, so your selectors weren't working as intended. Use jQuery [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get around that, as shown.

Comment: Cool, thank you VERY much. I will put it in and test. Your solution is really neat and doesn't look at type or class it seems... Chris

Comment: It works at jsfiddle but not at inandrias.com?? I changed the call to google's jquery... Chris

Comment: @user1530235 You have an invalid character `});â€‹` at line 46 of your html. If you open your js console it will show you the error. Removing everything *after* the semi-colon will fix that

Comment: @user1530235 the illegal token is still there, just now on line 47 -- are you using dreamweaver or another IDE to edit this? It's probably appending the token even if you can't see it. Try editing the plain-text of the page.

Comment: @user1530235 I am looking at the raw source of your webpage in my browser (chrome and ff). Go to the page, right-click, and press 'view page source' and you should see it

Comment: OK, gotcha, gone now. I added a third level under the Maintenance, Subfile maintenance buttons but they're not working...

Comment: @user Which browser are you using? IE, FF, Chrome all have built in js debuggers. In FF you can do Tools>Web Dev.>Web Console to open the console. This will show you errors in your code. Your current error (as shown in the console) is a typo in `$(".menuA").not(this).filter("[nme='"name"']").removeClass("menuA-open");` (line 24) It should be `$(".menuA").not(this).filter("[name='"+name+"']").removeClass("menuA-open");`

Comment: I'm using FF mainly but also testing on IE.
Yes, I saw the error eventually (the hard way)
Thank you for the debugger info

Comment: @user1530235 No problem, glad to help. Please accept the answer if this was helpful (there a little check mark at the side of the answer you can click and it will turn green)

Comment: I will do that though I'm still battling with a number of related issues, like, the fieldsets for the second level down can't be found using next(): returns "undefined".